# ZXing Barcode Scanner WinRT can't start StartPreviewAsync()

Tags: c#, windows-8, winrt-xaml, webcam, zxing

I run the following lines to get a preview of my webcam:

```
...
public MediaCapture VideoCaptureSource { get; set; }
var cameras = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(DeviceClass.VideoCapture);

if (cameras.Count == 1)
{
  settings = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings { VideoDeviceId = cameras[0].Id };
}
else
{
  settings = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings { VideoDeviceId = cameras[1].Id };
}

await _mediaCapture.InitializeAsync(settings);
VideoCaptureSource = _mediaCapture;
await VideoCaptureSource.StartPreviewAsync();
...
```

Here's my XAML:

```
<Canvas Width="640" Height="360">
  <CaptureElement Source="{Binding VideoCaptureSource}" Visibility="{Binding VideoCaptureVisibility}" Width="640" Height="360" />
  <Image Source="{Binding CaptureImageSource}" Visibility="{Binding CaptureImageVisibility, FallbackValue=Collapsed}" Width="640" Height="360" />
</Canvas>
```

Everything works fine until I call the StartPreviewAsyn()-Method. Unfortunately, I only get a not-so-useful error message: "An unexpected error has occurred in the operation requested."
I tried to run the Code on my local machine as well as on the simulator. Has anyone an idea what I do wrong?

Environment is Windows 8.1, Caliburn.Micro, ZXing.Net 0.12.0.0, VS 2013

Comment: Did you get this to work with Christoph’s answer below?

Comment: I haven't tried it personally, but a collegue of mine told me that this didn't work neither. Unfortunately I cannot tell you exactly why. But we will have to find a solution for this sooner or later, so as soon as we get it to work I will update this post.

Comment: @muetzenflo any news on this field? I'm facing the same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently ran into the same problem. It seems that binding the video source is quite tricky, because you need to initialise, set and start the preview stream in the right order. I fixed the issue using an attached property:

```
/// <summary>
/// This utility class provides an attached property that enables us to
/// bind the source of a <see cref="CaptureElement"/>.
/// </summary>
public static class VideoSourceBinding {

    public static MediaCapture GetVideoSource(DependencyObject obj) {
        return (MediaCapture) obj.GetValue(VideoSourceProperty);
    }

    public static void SetVideoSource(DependencyObject obj,
            MediaCapture value) {
        obj.SetValue(VideoSourceProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty VideoSourceProperty
        = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("VideoSource",
        typeof(MediaCapture),
        typeof(VideoSourceBinding),
        new PropertyMetadata(null, onVideoSourcePropertyChanged));

    private static async void onVideoSourcePropertyChanged(
            DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
        Debug.Assert(d is CaptureElement);
        Debug.Assert(e.Property == VideoSourceBinding.VideoSourceProperty);

        CaptureElement preview = d as CaptureElement;

        if (d != null) {
            if (preview.Source != null) {
                // If another camera was attached before, stop it.
                await preview.Source.StopPreviewAsync();
            }

            try {
                preview.Source = (MediaCapture) e.NewValue;
            } catch {
                // The property change occurred before the the video source
                // was properly initialised. In this case, we ignore the
                // change and wait for the source to fire the event again
                // once the initialisation was completed.
                // Important: The source must actually change in order for
                // the event to be fired (the attached property will detect
                // if the same object was re-set) and ignore this.
                preview.Source = null;
            }

            if (preview.Source != null) {
                // Start the preview stream.
                await preview.Source.StartPreviewAsync();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The video source is then bound like this:

```
<CaptureElement u:VideoSourceBinding.VideoSource="{Binding VideoCapture}" />
```

Note that the order in which you do things in the view model is important:

```
public class ViewModel : Screen {
    // Note: The sample uses a Caliburn Micro base class - this is, however, not
    // a requirement.

    public MediaCapture VideoCapture {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Starts the video preview.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Call this method whenever it is necessary to (re-) start the preview, eg
    /// if the page is activated or if the settings have changed.
    /// </remarks>
    private async void startVideo() {
        var captureSettings = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings() {
            StreamingCaptureMode = StreamingCaptureMode.Video
        };
        // Set a NEW MediaCapture! Do not re-use the old one, because the property 
        // change event of the attached property will not fire otherwise.
        this.VideoCapture = new MediaCapture();
        await this.videoCapture.InitializeAsync(captureSettings);
        // Notify the UI about a new video source AFTER the initialisation completed. It 
        // is important to await the initialisation here.
        this.NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => this.VideoCapture);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I will try out your code as soon as the project goes on again (right now it's on standby) and mark it as correct answer if it works.

Comment: Why is `VideoCapture` capitalized on the `CaptureElement`, but lowercased in `this.videoCapture`, except for the last line `this.NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => this.VideoCapture);`?

Comment: `VideoSourceBinding.VideoSource="{Binding VideoCapture}"` produces: An exception of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in MyApp.WindowsPhone.exe but was not handled in user code
WinRT information: Cannot deserialize XBF metadata property list as '%1' was not found in type '%0'. [Line: 0 Position: 0]
Additional information: The text associated with this error code could not be found.

Cannot deserialize XBF metadata property list as '%1' was not found in type '%0'. [Line: 0 Position: 0]

The program '[692] MyApp.WindowsPhone.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).

Comment: Are you trying to run that code as universal app on a phone? I have tested it only on the Windows 8 WinRT so far, so I do not know whether it is working as Windows 8.1 universal app. As the error is a `XamlParseException` (just a guess): did you correctly setup the namespaces on your page? The Namespace containing the attached property must be `xmlns:u` if you copy the code directly.

Comment: `VideoCapture` initially was a read-only property like `public MediaCapture { get { return this.videoCapture; } }`, so I had to set the backing field directly. I have changed the sample code for more clarity and added some more details.

Comment: Trying to get it to work on a Windows Phone 8.1 app. Unfortunately, I keep getting the "Cannot deserialize XBF metadata property list as '%1' was not found in type '%0'" error. Namespaces are correctly set up. The utility class gets recognized. I believe the error has to do with the DependencyProperty and its typeof(MediaCapture). This could be a bug.

Comment: I have checked this - and I can reproduce the effect. I created a new universal app and added the code - it works for the WinRT part, but not on Windows Phone (the same error that you posted). So far, I have no solution for that.

Comment: Thanks, we finally implemented this feature and your answer was very helpful